# DataGridView doesn't show data at run time

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using a `DataGridView` in my C# project. I choose the data source from its wizard (not with code).

The wizard asks whether to copy the database file (sql compact or sdf file) to main data folder or connect to my created path. I choose the second option (my path).

Now when I check the preview data it shows my database recorded data but when I run the program there is no data showing in the cells.

Sorry for my very bad English. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you use **DataSet** or **Entity Data Model**? You should manually check the generated artifacts.

Comment: visualstudio wizard used DataSet itself.

Comment: Nima, see the form's `Load` event. There must be a line that loads the data. What do you see? Also check the `DataSource` property of your `DataGridView`.

Comment: yes.the line is : this.tEMPTableAdapter.Fill(this.tEMPDST.TEMP);

Comment: and datasource: tEMPBindingSource

Comment: Set a break-point on the line that loads the data (in the `Load` event). Check `tEMPDST.TEMP` and make sure it really contains data.

Comment: yes.tEMPDST.TEMP contains data.

Comment: In the designer, click on `tEMPBindingSource` and check it's `DataSource` and `DataMember`.

Comment: DataSource=tEMPDST and DataMember=TEMP

Comment: Oh! Nothing else comes to my mind! Can I have a remote desktop (using Ammyy or TeamViewer)? Are you Persian? I am.

Comment: yes i'm persian.i haven't any of the programs you says.but thanks for your concern and your time verymuch.i will try to copy sdf file in main folder because that way my program worked.